# Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda Navigator don't open on Windows

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I work with Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda on Windows 10, and I've never had any problems. However recently Anaconda Navigator 2020.5 started not opening and disappeared from my apps list. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, I followed all the steps and the installation went perfectly and Anaconda Navigator opened again, but Jupyter Notebook doesn't open the browser. I updated Anaconda, restarted the app and then Anaconda Navigator stopped working again. I tried one more reinstall and the problem was repeated, and now I can't access Jupyter Notebook anymore and I'm afraid of losing all my codes. I have no idea what's going wrong, can someone help me for God's sake. I also got two versions of Python installed, which is Python 3.8 and 3.9

Comment: You never lose your code because a software fails to work. If you have your files stored, you'd never lose your work. I suggest that you edit your question and add details of any error messages you get so people can help you.

Comment: Thank you!!!! The thing is I didn't get any message error, it just simply doesn't open the browser when I click "Launch" on Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Navigator

Comment: I got your point. It happens a lot. Just copy the URL of the local host that appears after loading in the terminal and paste it to the browser. You're always welcome!

Comment: I would try this, but the Anaconda is not opening again, neither Jupyter terminal. I guess I'll have to reinstall it again.